# How to connect an LED to Arduino LilyPad Mp3

Tags: led, switch

can anyone help me with connecting LED to Arduino LilyPad Mp3  in a way, that each switch (1 of 5) light up a different LED?

I tried connecting an LED between the switch and the board, then the LED light up, but the speaker does not play the audio file.

I also tried connecting an LED directly to the speaker, then LED lights up and the speaker plays the sound file, but the problem is that all of the LED´s light up at the same time....

Comment: What kind of switches? How are they wired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try connecting the anode side of your LEDs through a current limiting resistor to the positive side of the supply.  Then connecting the cathode side of the LED to the switched pin on the Arduino LilyPad Mp3.  So, in this diagram:

[image]

...that would be the pads where the switches are connected.

The current limiting resistor depends on the specifications of the LED.  Check the voltage and current required to light the LED.  Subtract the voltage needed from your supply voltage.  Then use the V=IR equation and solve for R.  That is, V = the voltage difference between your supply and what is needed by the LED and I is the current (probably in milliamps, so watch your math!) that the LED needs to light up properly.  You will probably need small current limiting resistors somewhere around between 100 and 800 ohms.

Added later...

Thanks to @Gerben we have a diagram of what I was describing:

[image]

In Gerben's diagram he has used the regulated 3 volt output of the Arduino LilyPad Mp3.  We can double check all the pin labels using a diagram from Sparkfun:

[image]

You should be able to repeat this circuit for each switch.  Sparkfun has an LED tutorial [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/light-emitting-diodes-leds?_ga=1.1888825.965782605.1436615638).  But I'm not very happy with their guess approach when picking out a current limiting resistor.  Ah, [this tutorial](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/219) is much more to the point.

So, if we assume the LEDs you are using need 3mA @ 3V (remember to use values for YOUR LEDs!) and use this equation (Vs = supply voltage and Vf = LED voltage):

[image]

...then we set it up like (3 - 3) / (0.03) which is zero.  That's because I was using LEDs that work at 3 volts.  But if I used LEDs that worked at 3mA at 1.8V then I need... (3 - 1.8) / (0.03) = 40 ohm resistors.  Or there about. As most resistor values are on a log scale I suspect there should be a 47 ohm available.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KCUlD.png), right?